# android org.xmlpull.v1.xmlpullparserexception expected start_tag http //schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/ envelope position start tag

Tags: android, android-intent

I am suing asp.net webservice (visual studio 2008) for DBConnection in android.

It runs sucessfully.

My android code is:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final  AlertDialog ad=new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();


        TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvArray);

        Button btnCall=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCall);

        btnCall.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                CallSoap cs=new CallSoap();

                try
                {
                    String name=cs.Call();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    ad.setMessage(ex.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

And callsoap method:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope; 
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo; 
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

import android.widget.Toast;

public class CallSoap 
{ 
    public final String SOAP_ACTION ="http://tempuri.org/GetData";


    public  final String OPERATION_NAME = "GetData"; 

    public  final String WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";

    public  final String SOAP_ADDRESS = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/Service1.asmx";

    public CallSoap() 
    { 
    }


    public String  Call()
    {
        SoapObject req=new SoapObject(WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE, OPERATION_NAME);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                envelope.dotNet = true;
                //envelope.headerOut = security; // this is an Element[] created before
                envelope.encodingStyle = SoapEnvelope.ENC;
                envelope.setAddAdornments(false);
                envelope.implicitTypes = false;
     envelope.setOutputSoapObject(req);

     HttpTransportSE  httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(SOAP_ADDRESS);
     Object response=null;


     try
     {
     httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
     response = envelope.getResponse();
     //Toast.makeText(this, "this is my Toast message!!! =)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
     catch (Exception exception)
     {
     response=exception.toString();
     }
     return response.toString();
     }

}
```

It gives me Error when i click button on the app:

> android org.xmlpull.v1.xmlpullparserexception expected start_tag http
>   //schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/ envelope position start tag

I got many questions regarding this on stack.

I found that it generally happens due to wrong service method written.

But in my case i checked all of those. Every thing is right.

You can also check: I have snap of my running servive in which each and every thing is given:

[image]

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to put Port number instead of 8080

Comment: ohh thank you very much, was really a small mistake , but thanx a lot

Comment: with number do you meant of the localhost service port as screen shot  `52060` ? i have the same problem but i used port number 8089 as my web service local host but its working from eclipse and db at home but in work there is proxy issues is that give you a hint please help? am using thread to do the webservice soap call and do in back ground